# How to use values from the WITH table in my insert?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql, common-table-expression

After last answer I realized that I did things that was not needed. So I tried to rewrite it as following, but get error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION piljetter_system.update_search() RETURNS trigger AS $func_table$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO piljetter_system.search(consertid, document_tsvector)
SELECT  new.consertid, 
        setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(new.consertname, '')), 'A')
    || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(b.bandname , '')), 'B') -- Get bandname from id
    || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(s.stagename, '')), 'C') -- GET stagename from id
    || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(s.stagecountry, '')), 'D') -- GET stagecountry from id
    || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(s.stagecity, '')), 'E') -- GET stagecity from id
    || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(s.stagestreet, '')), 'F')
    -- GET stagestreet from id
FROM    piljetter_system.bands b, piljetter_system.stages s
WHERE   b.bandid = new.bandid AND s.stageid = new.stageid;
RETURN NEW.document_tsvector;
END
$func_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm triggering the function at insert and update at my conserts table.

The result I want is to insert a new line at search(consertid, document_tsvector) where the consertid = new.consertid and document_tsvector = new.consertname,  bandname from the new.bandid in the consert stagename, stagecountry, stagecity, stagestreet from the new.stageid.

ERROR:

> ERROR:  FEL:  unrecognized weight: 69 CONTEXT:  SQL-sats: "INSERT INTO
>   piljetter_system.search(consertid, document_tsvector)
>       SELECT  new.consertid, 
>             setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(new.consertname, '')), 'A')
>           || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(b.bandname , '')), 'B') -- Get bandname from id
>           || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(s.stagename, '')), 'C') -- GET stagename from id
>           || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(s.stagecountry, '')), 'D') -- GET stagecountry from id
>           || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(s.stagecity, '')), 'E') -- GET stagecity from id
>           || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(s.stagestreet, '')), 'F')        -- GET stagestreet from id  FROM
>   piljetter_system.bands b, piljetter_system.stages s   WHERE   b.bandid
>   = new.bandid AND s.stageid = new.stageid" PL/pgSQL-funktion piljetter_system.update_search() rad 3 vid SQL-sats

// OLD POST
I'm kinda new to functions and triggers and I'm doing a project at school. I want to make a trigger function that update another table based on what I insert into my conserts table.

My problem is that I need the stagename, stagecountry, stagecity, stagestreet from the stageid and also the bandname from the bandid and insert it into search colum document_tsvector. Below you can see the code I need to fix. I dont manage to get the info from the WITH tables inside my insert.

```
CREATE FUNCTION piljetter_system.update_search() RETURNS trigger AS $func_table$
BEGIN
    WITH band AS (
        SELECT bandname FROM piljetter_system.bands WHERE bandid = new.bandid
    ), stage AS (
        SELECT stagename, stagecountry, stagecity, stagestreet FROM piljetter_system.stages WHERE stageid = new.stageid
    )

    INSERT INTO piljetter_system.search(consertid, document_tsvector)
    VALUES (new.consertid, 
        setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(new.consertname, '')), 'A')
        || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(band.bandname , '')), 'B') -- Get bandname from id
        || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(stage.stagename, '')), 'C') -- GET stagename from id
        || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(stage.stagecountry, '')), 'D') -- GET stagecountry from id
        || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(stage.stagecity, '')), 'E') -- GET stagecity from id
        || setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(stage.stagestreet, '')), 'F')    -- GET stagestreet from id
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END
$func_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Pictures of the tables;
[bands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pTvA.png)

[conserts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLOKl.png)

[stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KdF9.png)

[search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmSu6.png)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Added some more info.

Comment: Weights E and F do not exist in a standard installation, only A through D.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it with WITH?  Why not just run two queries storing the values into variables, and then use the variables in the INSERT?

Anyway, you would just select from the CTE tables.

```
INSERT INTO piljetter_system.search(consertid, document_tsvector)
select new.consertid, ...
    from band, stage
```

But it looks like your trigger is inserting into the same table it was just called for. That is wrong. If your goal is to set document_tsvector, you should just assign a value to NEW.document_tsvector before you RETURN NEW.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have updated the thread now and realized my errors in using WITH.
However I try  your way and still get errors.